# how to retrieve facebook page wall posts update in external site

Tags: javascript

I need to publish landing tab wall posts of a [page](http://www.facebook.com/smartdeals) on my website using php and javascript,can anybody tell me how to implement this ,as i thought it can be done with FQL via page table but there is no any related field i found.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Graph API to retrieve posts for a page: https://graph.facebook.com/SmartDeals/posts

You can use either PHP and JavaScript to parse that JSON and display whatever you'd like.

The complete list of things you can retrieve for your page is documented under the Connections section at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page